# No encuentro «Enable runtime Themes»

Tags: delphi

Aplique un tema a mi aplicacion y para quitarlo me dicen que haga click en «Enable runtime Themes». Pero no encuentro esa opcion.

[image]

Edito: en otro proyecto la ventana es distinta. y en la ventana principal dice "32bits windows":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa los ficheros DPR de ambos proyectos, a ver si encuentras diferencias.

Comment: si hago click derecho sobre el exe y pongo view source en la IDE ese seria el dpr

Comment: No veo diferencias..solo estan las unidades

Comment: La siguiente opción es crear un nuevo proyecto y añadir todas las unidades del tuyo.

Comment: ok gracias por el consejo